# Where is the source code for realm DB core?

Tags: realm-list, realm

To much of my disappointment https://github.com/realm/realm-java doesn't actually have the actual realm code, just some binding. I can't risk including some random binary code into my app, that's why I'd like to build the whole thing from sources myself.
Or wait, is Realm actually open source?

Comment: The realm **core** is not open-source(d yet?): https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/LICENSE#L210-L243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our binding code (Java / JNI) is open source under Apache 2. The core database is still closed source. So I am sorry if that is a deal breaker for you.

We said from the start that we will be open sourcing Realm Core under Apache 2, and that is still the plan: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#i-see-references-to-a-core-in-the-code-what-is-that

Comment: Following this up! The source code for Realm Core was released today! https://github.com/realm/realm-core